# Using Regex to split hashtag and search items

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex expression to list the hashtags in a search entered into my app that looks like this:

```
text.match(/#[a-z]+/gi);
```

and a regex expression to list all the words in a search

```
text.match(/\S+\s*/g);
```

What I want to be able to do is to split hashtags and words into two separate lists so I want to be able to update the second regex expression so that it ignores hashtags. How would I achieve this?

For example, if the input is:

`"Hello this is #my #question for today"`

The expected output should be 2 arrays:

```
[Hello, this, is, for, today], 
[my, question]
```

I would also like to make the hashtag regex return the words without the hashtags if possible otherwise I could just string split the words in the array later if not possible

Comment: Can you give an example of the search string and the current output and a example of your expected output?? Thank you.

Comment: @NewToJS Thank you for your response. I have included the expected outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with both negative and positive lookbehinds. Obviously, the negative lookbehinds will match works without your 'hash tags', and the positive will match on the ones with them.

---

### Negative LookBehind to match your normal search terms

```
/\b(?<!#)[^#\s]+/g
```

- `\b` ensures you are looking at the beginning of a word
- `(?<!)` is a negative lookbehind. Prevents the match of `#`

#### [Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/yET0DZ/4/)

---

### Positive LookBehind to match your "hashed" words

```
/(?<=#)\w+/g
```

- `(?<=)` is a positive lookbehind, allows a match if `#` is found behind `\w+`

#### [Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/yET0DZ/3/)

---

[Additional information](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) regarding Lookarounds

Answer (score 0):

You can simply split on `space` characters and than you can check if the word starts with `#` or not using this regex

```
`/^#.+/`
```

The above regex with match `#` followed by atleast one character, if you want to match single `#` also as than you can simply use `startsWith`

```
/^#.+/.test(inp)   ---> inp.startsWith('#')
```

```js
let str = `Hello this is #my #question for today`

let {withHash,withOutHash} = str.split(/\s+/).reduce((op,inp)=>{
  let hash = /^#.+/.test(inp)
  let key = hash ? 'withHash' : 'withOutHash'
  op[key] = op[key] || []
  op[key].push(inp)
  return op
},{})


console.log(withHash)
console.log(withOutHash)
```